# ReplyingKafkaTemplate dynamic requesttopic and requestreplytopic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement synchronous request-response use case where producer will send message to **requesttopic** and wait for response from consumer to act on it and send back on **requestreplytopic**

I want to use request topic and corresponding requestreply topic dynamically generated on the basis of request sent from user (UI). lets say if user is bidding for product , then particular productid will be request topic and ${productid}_resp can be reply topic. There can be multiple bids (messages) will hit message broker and response will return back to UI.

With this implementation I am planning to use product id as topic and read all its messages from beginning when needed to query all bids placed on product.

I am not sure if this is correct use case or not to use replyingKafkaTemplate, but can we create replaying kafka template dynamically ?

```
@Value("${kafka.topic.requestreply-topic}")
private String requestReplyTopic;

@Bean
public <T> KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, ResponseBase<T>> replyContainer(
        ConsumerFactory<String, ResponseBase<T>> cf) {
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
}
```

and

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.request-topic}", errorHandler = "listen3ErrorHandler")
@SendTo
public ResponseBase<Object> listen(CreateBidRequest request) throws BidException {
    Product product = productRepository.findById(request.getProductId()).orElseThrow(() -> new BidException(ErrorCode.INVALID_PRODUCT_ID));
    Bid bid = Bid.builder().bidId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).bidAmount(request.getBidAmount()).product(product).build();
    bidRepository.save(bid);
    return ResponseBase.builder().response(bid).build();
}
```

complete code -> https://github.com/harshal2211/kafka-demo/

Comment: Can you explain, please, the reasoning behind a decision to use dynamic topics for this task? Why all the messages cannot go to the same topic and wait for replies from different but still the same topic? The `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` and `@KafkaListener` with `@SendTo` do the proper correlation between request and reply by default. It is really going to be counterproductive to create `KafkaConsumer` and, therefore, `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` for every single new topics...

Comment: @ArtemBilan I want to use product id as topic so that I can listen all the successful bids saved in database (messages starting from offset 0) on demand basis when UI need to query all bids on product without  querying database.

Comment: This doesn’t sound as a correct usage of the messaging at all… anyway you can use product Id as a key to partition those records properly. If you still insist for Kafka , the consider to investigate Kafka Streams or KSQL.